# Mapping Input fields to new output fields for serialization in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, datacontractserializer

I mention C# in my title but this is a generic programming question.
I am just looking to find the best approach to do the following:

I have tableA which contains the following fields

```
ID : 1
ProjectName : "Test"
City : "NY"
Size : 100
Location : "USA"
```

Now I need to serialize that table for a 3rd party application however I the application uses a generic data contract (see below) and in addition the field names would have to be slightly modified. So the above table would be serialized as follows:

```
<Object>
<type>Project</type>
<Fields>
<Key>NameofProject</Key><Value>Test</value>
<Key>ProjectCity</Key><Value>NY</value>
<Key>ProjectLocation</Key><Value>USA</value>
</Fields>
</Object>
```

As you can see I needed to map the fields from TableA into new field names/keys:

```
ProjectName -> NameofProject
City -> ProjectCity
Location ->ProjectLocation
```

This is how I would achieve the above:
- Create a mapping table which stores the mapping relationships as described above

```
InputField -> OutputKey
ProjectName -> NameofProject
City -> ProjectCity
Location ->ProjectLocation

I would then load the data from this table into a Set
I would then loop through each row of the input
- for each column in the row I would get the OutputKey based on the InputField as stored in my mapping Set, and build the xml
```

I assume storing a small amount of info in a Set and then doing the lookups for each field shouldnt be too bad. But I am not an experienced C# user so am wondering if there is a better way to do this in c#. 
Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
A comment suggested using XSLT - its a good idea but due to other complexities of this task its better for me to build the xml in code based on a data contract. Is there any way to achive the mapping via a sql join of the input data table and the mapping table?

Comment: You can use the built in Xml Serializer and then use appropriate XSLT and transform the serialized input to the ouput and this XSLT can be obtained from a config file or from the table in db so it can change dynamically without code recompile

Comment: that sounds like an interesting idea. I have not worked much with XSLT before - to know how to do this but will look into it.Is there no way to do the mapping on the field names when querying the table by means of a join to the mapping table?

Comment: Also - I need to use a data contract shared by the application so its not ideal to do the mapping via XSLT. And for other reasons that are going to make it complex

Answer (score 1):

In case of you having a fixed set of mapping, you can get this done using `DataContractSerializer` or via the `XmlSerializer` and then decorating the members with a different name like in the following sample.

The first one uses the `DataContractSerializer` and the latter uses `XmlSerializer`

```
[DataContract]
public class Project
{
    [DataMember(Name = "NameOfTheProject")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProjectLocation")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Project1
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ProjectName")]
    public string ProjName { get; set; }
}
```

As we see here, the model will mimic your table structure and the Attributes will be used to present the data with custom name for the properties when serialized.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I use this. I already have a data contract that defines the output xml in the generic form (<key>Keyname</key><value>Value</value>) and was going to build objects based on that data contract and send that to the application. (via RESTful API and serialization). When will I apply this mapping and how will I use it? THanks